# If currentUser() is deprecated, how can I use .then?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

since I just learning flutter and
I kinda follow old videos so most of the code for firebase were deprecated.

would like to know if there's any link to it for revisions

```
firebaseAuth.currentUser.then((user){
  if(user != null){
    setState(() => isLoggedIn = true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting `currentUser` actually got easier. Now it's not a future, so you don't have to `await` or use `then`. You can get the user like this:

```
final user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
if(user != null){
    setState(() => isLoggedIn = true);
}
```

Comment: might want `isLoggedin` to fix the spelling error... "logedin" would be pronounced "lojed in" with a j sound. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state